# Why can't I upload images in production mode in Codeigniter 4?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

Everything works fine on the local server when using development or production modes. Also on hosting if I use development mode.
But when using production mode on hosting, I can't upload images.
No errors are shown, but no new files are in the folder.

```
$name= $photo->getRandomName();
  if ($photo->move('public/dist/photo', $name)) {
     $this->model->update(session()->get('data_id'),[
          'photo' => $name
     ]);
     if (isset($dataphoto['photo'])) unlink('public/dist/photo/'.$dataphoto['photo']);
     echo json_encode(['status' => TRUE]);
  }
```

I hope my application can run well in production mode.

Comment: What's in `$dataphoto['photo']`? Please refer to: [Working with Uploaded Files](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/libraries/uploaded_files.html) Lastly, it appears as if you're moving and deleting the same file afterward.

Comment: The function that I created is for uploading user photo or changing it. So It's only for deleting old photo.
If using development env, It runs fine.